# iterating through map and getting stack overflow error clojure

Tags: clojure, hashmap

for an assignment I need to create a map from a text file in clojure, which I am new to. I'm specifically using a hash-map...but it's possible I should be using another type of map. I'm hoping someone here can answer that for me. I did try changing my hash-map to sorted-map but it gave me the same problem.

The first character in every line in the file is the key and the whole line is the value. The key is a  number from 0-9999. There are 10,000 lines and each number after the first number in a line is a random number between 0 and 9999.
I've created the hashmap successfully I think. At least, its not giving me an error when I just run that code. However when I try to iterate through it, printing every value for keys 0-9999 it gives me a stack overflow error right at the middle of line 2764(in the text file). I'm hoping someone can tell me why it's doing this and a better way to do it?
Here's my code:

```
(ns clojure-project-441.core
(:gen-class))

(defn -main 
[& args]
(def pages(def hash-map (file)))
(iter 0)



)
(-main)


(defn file []
   (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "pages.txt")]
   (reduce conj [] (line-seq rdr))))


(defn iter [n]

(doseq [keyval (pages n)] (print keyval))

(if (< n 10000)
(iter (inc n))

)


)
```

[here's a screenshot of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJbIp.png)

If it's relevant at all I'm using repl.it as my IDE.

Here are some screenshots of the text file, for clarity.

[beginning of text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIecb.png)

[where the error is being thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C2mN.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the specific problem that causes the exception to be thrown is caused because `iter` calls itself recursively too many times before hitting the 10,000 line limit.

There some issues in your code that are very common to all people learning Clojure; I'll try to explain:

- `def` is used to define top-level names. They correspond with the concept of constants in the global scope on other programming languages. Think of using `def` in the same way you would use `defn` to define functions. In your code, you probably want to use `let` to give names to intermediate results, like:

```clj
(let [uno 1
      dos 2]
  (+ uno dos)) ;; returns 3
```

- You are using the name `hash-map` to bind it to some result, but that will get in the way if you want to use the *function* `hash-map` that is used to create maps. Try renaming it to `my-map` or similar.
- To call a function recursively without blowing the stack you'll need to use `recur` for reasons that are a bit long to explain. See the factorial example here: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/recur

My advice would be to think of this assignment as a pipeline composed of the following small functions:

- A function that reads the lines from the file (you already have this)
- A function that, given a line, returns a pair: the first element of the pair is the first number of the line, the second element is the whole line (the input parameter) OR
- A function that reads the first number of the line
- To build the map, you have a few options; two off the top of my mind:

  - Use a `loop` construct and, for each line, "update" the hash-map to include a new key-value pair (the key is the first number, the value is the whole line), then return the whole hash-map you've built
  - Use a `reduce` operation: you create a collection of key-value pairs, then tell `reduce` to merge, one step at a time, into the original hash-map. The result is the hash-map you want

I think the key is to get familiar with the functions that you can use and build small functions that you can test in isolation and try to group them conveniently to solve your problem. Try to get familiar with functions like `hash-map`, `assoc`, `let`, `loop` and `recur`. There's a great documentation site at https://clojuredocs.org/ that also includes examples that will help you understand each function.

Comment: Hi, so I replaced ```(def pages(def hash-map (file)))``` with a let block like you suggested and that seems to work fine. I also changed the name to first-map. when I put (first-map 0) into the repl it seems to send me the correct line, so I'm confused about where you said "A function that, given a line, returns a pair: the first element of the pair is the first number of the line, the second element is the whole line (the input parameter) OR
A function that reads the first number of the line" I'm not sure what the purpose of this is? Can you explain, Am I missing something? Very sorry

Comment: The idea here is to build key-value pairs, that you can use to build your whole map, one key-value pair at a time. You can either use `assoc` one key and value in a loop, or you can use a `reduce` operation to `merge` small maps into one big map.

Comment: I looked at the documentation for ```assoc``` do you mean like this?
```(defn getmap []
(def my-map {})
(loop[n 0]
(when (< n 9999)
(assoc my-map :n (pages n))
(recur (inc n))

)

))```  I renamed the text file to pages as that made more sense

Comment: See this gist for some examples: https://gist.github.com/dfuenzalida/f2cf44d6d2333365b8f53d55904c56f8

Comment: thank you, just to make sure how can I call a value of this map with a key? I used a let block to store the returned map in a variable and when I put ```mapname :0``` into the repl it returns nil. Is that the correct way to do that?

Comment: Clojure maps can have elements of any type as keys and values, and maps are also functions that take a key as argument and return the value for the given key or `nil` if not found. Now, `:0` is a `keyword` (all keywords start with `:`) which is different from the number `0`. Probably the key you want is `0` and not `:0`. You can get the keys of a map with `(keys my-map)`. See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keys

Comment: I did ```(keys my-map)``` into the repl and it gives me a bunch of strings of numbers, but those should be the values. if I copy and paste one of the keys like ```(my-map "4703 2725 4998 3904 4726 6116 182 6891 9862 2765 8954 3721 2157 7158 6948 ")``` then it just spits that exact thing back to me. I did try modifying the code because it seems like it might be taking the lines and for some reason making that both the key and value but I haven't been able to get anywhere with that. Any advice? Sorry for taking up your time

Comment: it looks you are not creating proper keys for your map. From your screenshot it looks like the key should be the first number in the line, so definitely you need a function that, given a line as argument, returns the first number. One option could be to split the line by spaces, take the first element, read the element as a number. Check the following, including the examples: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/first and https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read-string